# Scheduling with quartz every 30 minutes from 7:45 to 17:15

Tags: java, cron, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I am having problems scheduling my job with quartz...
I cannot find an expression which lets me run my job from 7:45 to 17:15 every half hour...
I have tried this

```
    0 15/30 7-17 ? * * *
```

but it fires at 17:45, and I don't want it.
Does anybody know any way to do this without splitting the expression?
I know that these expressions

```
    0 15 8-17 ? * * *
    0 45 7-16 ? * * *
```

would fit but I'd rather use a single one if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression **0 45/30 07-17 * * ?** fires every 30 minutes, starts at 7:45 and ends at 17:**45** every day. In my opinion, it's not possible to schedule a job to start at 7:45 and end at 17:**15** using **only one** cron expression.

Thanks